# What's the reason of this error (inheriting class whith generic)?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIn2Z.png)
I'm creating a pack of generic classes, gradually specifying generic type from **T** to **example_of_stored_class**.

```
public class ModifiedList<example_of_stored_class> : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class> 
{
    public void someMethod ()
    {
    }
}

public class AdvancedList<T> : List<T> where T : example_of_stored_class
{
    public AdvancedList ()
        {

        }
}
public class example_of_stored_class
{
    public string s = "Hi, i'm an example_of_stored_class!";
}
```

Error msg:

> The type 'example_of_stored_class' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AdvancedList'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'example_of_stored_class' to **'R7_app**.example_of_stored_class'.

The question is -  what's the difference between 'example_of_stored_class' and 'R7_app.example_of_stored_class'? Why it happens?

Comment: Please post errors as text, in the body of your question. Screenshots are very inconvenient for those of us reading your question, and they're not searchable.

Comment: Is R7_app your class or your namespace?

Comment: Have you defined `example_of_stored_class` twice accidentally, once in a global namespace and once in the `R7_app` namespace?

Comment: Note that `public class ModifiedList<example_of_stored_class>` is defining a generic type named `example_of_stored_class` not using the class type `example_of_stored_class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first appearance of `example_of_stored_class` here is a *type parameter*, because it appears in angle brackets after the class name in a class definition: By the rules of C#, you're saying that `ModifiedClass` takes a type parameter named `example_of_stored_class`. Somebody using your class could provide any actual type for that parameter (at least, if the whole thing compiled to begin with):

```
var x = new ModifiedList<int>();
var y = new ModifiedList<String>();
```

But then you inherit this generic class from another generic class, where you *supply* `example_of_stored_class` as the *value* of AdvancedList's type parameter. We're not defining AdvancedList here, so the type in the angle brackets is interpreted as a type you want to use for the type parameter.

You've found a way to make `example_of_stored_class` mean two different things in the same line, and confusion has resulted.

```
public class ModifiedList<example_of_stored_class> 
    : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
```

This will compile:

```
public class ModifiedList<T> : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

But I suspect that you really want `ModifiedList<T>` to inherit from an `AdvancedList<T>` with the *same* type parameter:

```
public class ModifiedList<MyT> : AdvancedList<MyT>
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Or else this -- you want example_of_stored_class to be the only type parameter in the picture. I that case, ModifiedList isn't generic. It's inheriting from a "realized" generic class, one that already has a type parameter supplied.

```
public class ModifiedList : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This was it:

```
public class ModifiedList : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

There was an error in ModifiedList declaration. I didn't need to declare **example_of_stored_class** twice. Thanks, Ed Plunkett!

Answer (score 1):

You can't write:

```
ModifiedList<example_of_stored_class> : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
```

Because in the first part of the statement, you must indicate a generic parameter that is used for "substitution".

As is it can't be a type.

You must write:

```
ModifiedList<T> : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
```

Where T is not a code defined type as a class because it is a template artifact.

The word "template" here refers to C++ templates even C# generics are not the same as C++ templates, but historically generics comes from templates.

[Generic type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)

Did you simply want to write:

```
ModifiedList : AdvancedList<example_of_stored_class>
```

Comment: Are you missing `public class` prefixes?